# Efeito de click no botão

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber se é possível, em um Button, ter aquele efeito de click, ou seja, ele "afundar" e "voltar ao normal". Isso é uma propriedade ou eu deveria usar sim um ImageButton com as imagens deste "efeito"?
Segue abaixo meu XML de controle que criei no drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/cardview_dark_background" />
            <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

Analisando o que você colocou na pergunta, o `drawable` falta o seguinte:

Código:

```js
 <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/cardview_dark_background" /><!-- USE OUTRA COR! -->
            <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa criar um Shape diferente para o "estado":

**botao_selecionado.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#DBDBDB" />
    <corners android:radius="14dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#DBDBDB" />
</shape>
```

**botao_normal.xml**:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#F2F2F2" />
    <corners android:radius="14dp" />


    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#DBDBDB" />
</shape>
```

E o drawable com o botão em si, **botao.xml**:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/botao_selecionado" android:state_pressed="true" /> <!-- pressionado -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/botao_selecionado" android:state_focused="true" /> <!-- com foco -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/botao_normal" /> <!-- normal-->
</selector>
```

Então no seu layout é só você atribuir o `botao.xml` como background:

`android:background="@drawable/botao"`